# images in a grid that shimmy

Tags: css, gridview

Hi guys not sure what you would call images that pop, shimmy or highlight. on this website [follow your feet website](https://www.follow-your-feet.com/) they have a grid section of destinations and when you hover your mouse over a destination it pops to be bigger than the others.

any idea what csss code they have used for this

Comment: Right-click an element and select "inspect" to inspect the code and see what css has been used there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score -1):

So you'd want something like this?

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/t93g5xdq/1/)

In this case, add the following code to your `img` tag in your CSS.

```
.myimage {
     -moz-transition:all 0.3s;
     -webkit-transition:all 0.3s;
      transition:all 0.3s
 }

 .myimage:hover {
     -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
     transform: scale(1.5)
 }
```